# Авторизация asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
Добрый день, не могу сделать авторизацию на сайте asp.net mvc.
Если, скажем будет всего 5 пользователей и не создавать базу, а статично создать пользователей и пароли. Как это сделать?
Спасибо
```

Answer (score 2):

как вариант можно забить в web.config. посмотри вот [тут](http://smarly.net/pro-asp-net-mvc-4/introducing-asp-net-mvc-4/sportsstore-security-finishing-touches/securing-the-administration-controller)